# Python subprocess permissionerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissionerror

When I try to execute a file which is located inside the Program Files directory, I get a PermissionError execption.

excat error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Build.py", line 24, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen([buildCMD], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
[23948] Failed to execute script 'Build' due to unhandled exception!
```

Code:

```
import subprocess
buildCMD = '"C:/Program Files/Microchip/xc8/v2.32/bin/xc8-cc.exe" -mcpu=16f1787 -Wl,-Map=.build/main.build.map  -DXPRJ_default=default  -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1   -mdfp=C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.50/packs/Microchip/PIC12-16F1xxx_DFP/1.2.63/xc8  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx32 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto -Wl,--memorysummary,.build/memoryfile.xml -o .build/main.build.hex main.c'

subprocess.Popen([buildCMD], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Are you on linux?

Comment: No, Im on windows right now. Otherwise I could probably fix it with chmod +x

Comment: Check if the path is the correct one or maybe use a raw string could help `r''`

Comment: @TTT2 It's the correct path, but maybe the space in "Program Files" is a problem. It shouldnt tho, because I used double quotes for the path.

Comment: You didn't use double quotes around the other path with a space in it. Maybe reload the page so you can see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string as a list is doubly wrong, though Windows is somewhat more forgiving than real computers here. You want either

```
subprocess.run([
    "C:/Program Files/Microchip/xc8/v2.32/bin/xc8-cc.exe",
    "-mcpu=16f1787", "-Wl,-Map=.build/main.build.map",
    "-DXPRJ_default=default", "-Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1",
    "-mdfp=C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.50/packs/Microchip/PIC12-16F1xxx_DFP/1.2.63/xc8",
    "-fno-short-double", "-fno-short-float", "-fasmfile",
    "-maddrqual=ignore", "-xassembler-with-cpp", "-mwarn=-3",
    "-Wa,-a", "-msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file",
    "-ginhx32", "-Wl,--data-init", "-mno-keep-startup",
    "-mno-osccal", "-mno-resetbits", "-mno-save-resetbits",
    "-mno-download", "-mno-stackcall", "-std=c99", "-gdwarf-3",
    "-mstack=compiled:auto:auto",
    "-Wl,--memorysummary,.build/memoryfile.xml",
    "-o", ".build/main.build.hex", "main.c"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    check=True)
```

or the same as a string (but then with correct quoting around the arguments with spaces in them, notably `-mdfp=C:/Program Files/...`) and with `shell=True` (which however [you usually want to avoid.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Notice also the addition of `check=True` to have Python raise an exception if the subprocess fails, and the preference for `subprocess.run()` over `subprocess.Popen` unless you specifically require the subprocess to run alongside with your Python script, and then commit to managing the process object until it is terminated.

Comment: The options with commas inside them look weird, but I assume you know what you are doing there.